# New line in dynamically generated text view in kotlin android

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm a newbie with android kotlin development and was struggling with trying to make this work. I've a textview which is dynamically generated from the code. I've to represent a list of words (say 15 of them) in this way.

```html
word1     word2    word3     word4     word5
    word6      word7   word8     word9    word10
word11   word12    word13   word14     word15
```

Are there any code snippets or guidance anyone can share please?

I've tried a few options

- Trying with HTML formatting and adding line break
- New line in text("\n"), System.getProperty("line.separator")
- tv_dynamic.setLines(3)
  tv_dynamic.isSingleLine = false

The only other option will be creating multiple texts but thats a little clunky. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are these words also dynamic?

Comment: yes, the words are in an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Create a formatted placeholder for your strings in XML**

`strings.xml`

```
<string name="words">
%1$s \t %2$s \t %3$s \t %4$s \t %5$s
\n%6$s \t %7$s \t %8$s \t %9$s \t %10$s
\n%11$s \t %12$s \t %13$s \t %14$s \t %15$s
</string>
```

**Then reference the placeholder in your code***

`activity.kt`

```
val arr = ...
val formattedText = getString(R.string.words,
     arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]..., arr[14])
```

Comment: Thanks @giddy-naya, I tried that but that doesn't seem to be working unfortunately. Have you been able to make it work? Thanks for your efforts though.

Comment: Hi @giddy-naya, thank you very much. Sorry, I initially thought it wasn't working but looks like I'm able to see some positive result. Let me get back to you soon!!